# How do you clear the console in MATLAB?

Tags: matlab, console

How do you clear the console in MATLAB?

For example, I'm debugging a script that displays a *ton* of output. I want to clear the console on every run, so I don't have to look through output from old runs.

Answer (score 74, accepted):

Short answer, the [`clc`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/clc.html) function:

```
>> clc
```

You can also select **Edit** > **Clear Command Window** in the MATLAB desktop (older versions) or select **Clear Command Window** from the Command Window pull-down menu:

[image]

Answer (score 21):

```
>> clc %clear command
```

Related functions include:

```
>> clf %clear figure
>> cla %clear axis
>> close all %close all windows
>> clear %clear workspace of variables
```

Comment: Years ago, I always found myself typing "closeall", instead of "close all". Lazy fingers, but it naturally generates an error. The simple solution was to create a simple idiom, the closeall function on my system. Problem solved.

Comment: We used to have a function SHG (Show Graphics) from when computers were either in text or graphics mode.  We then made SHG bring up the figure.  In an effort to simplify the language we got rid of the command since figure(gcf) did the same thing.  Well, after one release of complaints...
>>edit shg
So you are not alone woodchips... :)

Answer (score 6):

One more option to achieve the clc is to right-clicking in the command window and choosing 'Clear command window'

Answer (score 3):

There is also a default shortcut for clearing command window, which is **CTRL+L**. That's probably the fastest way to clear the output.

Comment: At least for R2015a, there is no default shortcut for clearing the command window. It needs to be created first via Preferences -> Keyboard -> Shortcuts.

Comment: @dasdingonesin yeah the answer might be outdated now ;-)